# Unable to publish web service which is created in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

i am newbie to java/eclipse and also to creating web services.Now i am trying to host the web service which is created in java using eclipse.

http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/29

i am following the above link for my reference.

My problem is,i got struggle on after creating a web service.I have created a web service and run it through the tomcat server and its showing like the below image

[image]

this is the link of wsdl of my web service i got

"http://localhost:8080/ResourceA/services/Myservice?wsdl"

Now i need to know,what steps i want to do after these steps, to publish and run my web service through my cloud server?

Thanks in advance!..

Comment: Can you share web.xml and *.wsdd that would be there in your project? Also, did you try to see what services are listed in the services link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the project as a Web Archive (.war file) and deploy that on the server.