# How do I deploy a wsdl to tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, tomcat7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to publish web service which is created in java using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739868/unable-to-publish-web-service-which-is-created-in-java-using-eclipse)

I've been racking my brain over this for over a week.  I need to deploy a wsdl to my tomcat7 server in eclipse.  I know it depends on the metro runtime, and I don't need to do anything fancy.  I just want to hit it with a browser and see some pretty XML.  I'm fairly new to webservice development so I apologize if this question is sophomoric or has already been answered elsewhere but after trying every solution in my top 10 pages of google results and getting nowhere I think I may not even know enough about this topic to ask the right questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your WebService project as an WAR file and deploy it in Tomcat.